# Cypress asynchronous execution returns 4 same assertion

Tags: async-await, cypress, type-assertion

I have a question.
I am using Cypress for my automation and I started using async and await for my tests.
I am using POM design pattern.

My question:
If I execute the following test:

test.spec.ts class (test class)

```js
import { login_po } from "../pom/1.Chiquito/login_po";
const pom = new login_po()

describe("Put some name here.", async() => {
    it('TestCase1', async () => {
        await pom.navigateTo();
    });
});
```

My POM class.

```js
export class login_po {

    navigateTo() {
        cy
            .visit(`https://chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk/`)
            .url()
            .should('be.equal', 'https://chiquito-qa.omnifitrgsites.co.uk/').then(() => this.verifyAfterLogin());
    }

    verifyAfterLogin() {
        cy.get('.header__logo-img');
    }
}
```

When I execute the test - Cypress makes 4 (same) assertions.
[image]

If I remove 'async' - 'await' from the test class - Cypress makes 1 assertion.

```js
import { login_po } from "../pom/1.Chiquito/login_po";
const pom = new login_po()

describe("Put some name here.", () => {
    it('TestCase1', () => {
        pom.navigateTo();
    });
});
```

[image]

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

[Cypress commands are not promises](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#The-Cypress-Command-Queue), and their interaction with async/await will not happen as you expect. Additionally, while POM is feasible and reasonable to do within Cypress, [it is recommended that you use App Actions](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/) instead of a POM.